# Dropbox account as Wordpress uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress, dropbox

As I'm developing a site with the potential of holding a huge number of images I'm wondering if I can set the standard WordPress uploads folder to a Dropbox account?

And if so, how do I do that?

It would be great when I can implement it in a maner that even WordPress don't know it is a 'remote' folder. Media upload should work the same way as in a native WordPress setup.

I've read about the possibility to use another folder instead of `wp-content/uploads` but I could not find any info about using Dropbox for this.

Comment: @halfer, I don't understand your edit, just trying to ask my questions politely but ok, no harm done.

Comment: Hi A30. Historically I've noticed that questions that are exceedingly polite or that ask explicitly for help are sometimes (rightly or wrongly) interpreted as ingratiating or pleading, is sometimes added in lieu of prior research, and can get downvotes as a result. On a help site readers know that someone wants help, so it may be redundant. Of course, this is subjective - one person's begging is another person's civility! But succinct is good anyway.

Comment: Hi Halfer, thank you for your elaboration. I will try to avoid it in the future. BTW do you know a solution to my question as well? ;-)

Comment: Well, the advice from Cristiano looks very sound. There may be a plugin to do it already, but failing that I imagine the library linked to in that answer can be gotten working by looking at the examples in their documentation.

Comment: @A3O why don't you use CDN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. As long as you keep the same structure on Dropbox **and save Dropbox shareable links as meta data for both the original file and generated sizes**, a simple yet fully working setup for it would be something like the following, by using [thephpleague/flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) with their [Dropbox Adapter](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-dropbox):

**Step 1**

Add a file called `composer.json` to the root of your theme with this content:

```
{
  "require": {
    "league/flysystem": "^1",
    "league/flysystem-dropbox": "^1"
  }
}
```

**Step 2**

Install Composer by [following these instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

**Step 3**

Using the command line on your terminal/console, go to your theme directory and run:

```
composer install -o
```

**Step 4**

Create Dropbox App [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). 
I suggest that you select "App folder" as the type of access. 
A directory matching the name of you app will be created on the "Apps" directory at the root of your Dropbox account; This will be your "uploads" directory on Dropbox.

**Step 5**

Go to your app admin page and generate a new access token.
Save the access token somewhere and also copy the "App secret"

**Step 6**

Add the following to your `functions.php`:

```
use League\Flysystem\AdapterInterface;
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local as LocalAdapter;
use League\Flysystem\Dropbox\DropboxAdapter;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\MountManager;
use Dropbox\Client as DropboxClient;

// Autoload vendors
require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Class that will handle uploading to Dropbox
 * 
 */
class SO40950172Filesystem {

  /**
   * Contains several mounted filesystems
   * 
   * @var League\Flysystem\MountManager object
   */
  protected $filesystem;

  /**
   * Contains Dropbox client
   *
   * We need this accessible to create shareable links
   * 
   * @var Dropbox\Client object
   */
  protected $dropbox_client;

  /**
   * Instantiates this class
   */
  public function __construct() {

    // Get WordPress uploads directory info
    $uploads_info = wp_upload_dir();

    // Create Local filesystem
    $local_adapter = new LocalAdapter($uploads_info['basedir']);
    $local_fs      = new Filesystem($local_adapter, [
        'visibility' => AdapterInterface::VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
    ]);

    // Create Dropbox filesystem
    $this->dropbox_client  = new DropboxClient($app_access_token, $app_secret);
    $dropbox_adapter = new DropboxAdapter($this->dropbox_client, '/');
    $dropbox_fs      = new Filesystem($dropbox_adapter, [
      'visibility' => AdapterInterface::VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
    ]);

    // Set filesystem manager
    $this->filesystem = new MountManager([
      'local'   => $local_fs,
      'dropbox' => $dropbox_fs
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * Uploads file to Dropbox
   * 
   * @param  string $path Path to file
   * @return object       Current object
   */
  public function uploadToDropbox($path)
  {
    // Normalize path
    $path = static::getNormalizedPath($path);

    // Get content from the local file
    $content = $this->read("local://$path");

    // Push file to Dropbox
    $this->put("dropbox://$path", $content);

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Deletes file from Dropbox
   * 
   * @param  string $path Path to file
   * @return object       Current object
   */
  public function deleteFromDropbox($path)
  {
    // Normalize path
    $path = static::getNormalizedPath($path);

    // Delete file from Dropbox
    $this->delete("dropbox://$path");

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the unique identifier path section of a Dropbox URL
   * 
   * @param  string $path Path to file
   * @return string       Dropbox URL unique identifier
   */
  public function getDropboxUrlID($path)
  {
    // Normalize path
    $path = static::getNormalizedPath($path);

    // Get unique link
    $url = $this->dropbox_client->createShareableLink("/$path");

    // Parse URL to retrive its path
    $url_info = parse_url($url);
    $url_path = $url_info['path'];

    // Remove "s/" section and file name from the URL path
    $id = str_replace(['s/', basename($path)], '', $url_path);

    // Return Dropbox unique identifier for this file URL
    return trim($id, '/');
  }

  /**
   * Returns clean & relative paths
   * 
   * @param  string $path Raw path
   * @return string       Parsed path
   */
  public static function getNormalizedPath($path)
  {
    // Get WordPress uploads directory info
    $uploads_info = wp_upload_dir();

    // Remove uploads base path so that we end up
    // with the "/YYYY/MM/filename.extension" format
    $path = str_replace($uploads_info['basedir'], '', $path);

    // Remove uploads base url so that we end up
    // with the "/YYYY/MM/filename.extension" format
    $path = str_replace($uploads_info['baseurl'], '', $path);

    // Remove forward slashes on both ends
    $path = trim($path, '/');

    // Return path
    return $path;
  }

  /**
   * Making sure all calls go to $this->filesystem
   * 
   * @param  string $name Method name
   * @param  array  $args Method arguments
   * @return mixed        
   */
  public function __call($name, array $args)
  {
    if (method_exists($this->filesystem, $name))
      throw new \Exception("\League\Flysystem\MountManager doesn't have \"$name\" method");

    return call_user_func_array([$this->filesystem, $name], $args);
  }
}

// Manipulate media URLs sitewide
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'so_40950172_get_dropbox_url', 9, 2);

function so_40950172_get_dropbox_url($absolute_url, $post_id) {

  // Get normalized path
  $path = SO40950172Filesystem::getNormalizedPath($absolute_url);

  // Get only the filename
  $path = basename($path);

  // Get Dropbox URL unique ID
  $id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'dropbox_id_'. $path, true);

  // Return absolute URL
  return $id ? "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/$id/$path/?dl=0" : $path;
}

// Upload new and updated files to Dropbox
add_filter('wp_update_attachment_metadata', 'so_40950172_upload_to_dropbox', 9, 2);

function so_40950172_upload_to_dropbox($data, $post_id) {

  // Get filesystem
  $fs = new SO40950172Filesystem();

  // Upload original file to Dropbox
  $fs->uploadToDropbox($data['file']);

  // Add Dropbox URL unique ID to meta data
  add_post_meta($post_id, 'dropbox_id_'. basename($data['file']), $fs->getDropboxUrlID($data['file']));

  // Upload intermediate image sizes
  if (isset($data['sizes']) && $data['sizes']) {

    // Get year and month prefix (e.g /YYYY/MM) from original file
    $base_path = dirname($data['file']);

    // Loop through all sizes
    foreach ($data['sizes'] as $size_name => $size_data) {

      // Set path for current size
      $size_path = $base_path .'/'. $size_data['file'];

      // Upload size to Dropbox
      $fs->uploadToDropbox($size_path);

      // Add Dropbox URL unique ID to meta data
      add_post_meta($post_id, 'dropbox_id_'. basename($size_path), $fs->getDropboxUrlID($size_path));
    }
  }

  return $data;
}

// Delete Dropbox file
add_filter('wp_delete_file', 'so_40950172_delete_dropbox_file');

function so_40950172_delete_dropbox_file($absolute_path) {

  // Get filesystem
  $fs = new SO40950172Filesystem();

  // Delete file from Dropbox
  $fs->deleteFromDropbox($absolute_path);
}
```

**Step 7**

On the code your just pasted into `functions.php`:

- Replace `$app_access_token` with the Dropbox app access token you generated
- Replace `$app_secret` with the Dropbox app secret

**NOTES**

The original file and generated sizes will also be saved locally, but you don't need to worry about them. You can even delete the local file after confirmation of a successful upload, if you want and/or care about disk space.

I also tested the built-in image editor and it worked without any issues.

<s>If you ever need to move things on the Dropbox side and since there is no info saved on the database (this is just fine), all you need to do is to update the functions above.</s>
Apparently you can mirror the WordPress structure on Dropbox, but you can't simply link to them using a base URL and the WordPress uploads structure to get the URLs, you really need to get the [shareable link](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/167) for each original file and generated sizes and store something about them as metadata. On the code above I chose to only store the unique part of the URL as metadata, which really is the only unique thing about them.

I know this is off-topic, but I would recommend either AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage because you can access your files with the exact same file structure you have on Dropbox. No need to save anything as meta data.

Comment: Would deleting files locally cause some areas of the WP admin interface to crash, as it attempts to find a file that is not there? Or is everything URL based and will happily use external URLs pointing to a remote server?

Comment: @Cristiano, thank you for you answer. However, I'm not sure I understand it right. I'm hoping for a solution that everything stays the same for adding, editing and deleting media items for all users. It should just not use the uploads folder for the media but the one on dropbox. Wordpress should act as a kind of window to the DropBox account and I don't see in you answer that that is happening. Can your elaborate more?

Comment: The first function would modify all URLs for uploads sitewide, front and back-end. As long as you use the WordPress API to get URLs for any custom functionality, you should be fine. The solution I'm providing is the integration with WordPress you're looking for, as you're hooking into its features and simply adding the remote media management layer without modifying any of its core features. The default uploads folder and structure will be used by WordPress when you upload anything, but it will be replicated on Dropbox and your site will serve Dropbox URLs to your visitors and logged in users

Comment: @halfer the only issue I faced in the past happened whenever you wanted to edit an image within WordPress and it couldn't find the local file to apply any modifications you made, but I think WordPress v4 can handle remote URLs. Need to recheck on that and edit the answer if needed

Comment: @halfer I can confirm there are no issues with the built-in image editor

Comment: @Cristiano, I tried your solution but it is not working (yet) spending almost the whole day on it I'm getting an http error when adding media. The media is added to the local folder but I don't see it appearing in Dropbox. You are speaking about the Wordpress API to get URLs.... do I have to do anything with it? And the code line: `$this->dropbox_client  = new DropboxClient('s1ItAr4KKkIAAAAAAAF_uqxhlIczAZz2uwxfMrBvynsaBTvgUsY2O79tlgIu8tnT', 'vnvoubia9hrbkar');`
does it point to the right spot? I read about a client.... is that me? How do I have to read it?

Comment: @A3O My bad. I forgot to replace the credentials of my test Dropbox app with variables... You need to go to [dropbox.com/developers](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), create an app and within it create an access token (that you should keep secret) and then replace `$app_access_token` and `$app_secret` with the ones for your app.

When you're creating the app, you have the option to use the whole Dropbox or limit it to a specific directory, which I recommend. If you choose to use a specific directory, it will be created within the `Apps` directory.

Comment: @A3O When I talk about using the WordPress API to get URLs on your custom features, I'm talking about using stuff like `wp_get_attachment_url` and similar, instead of doing custom SQL queries and using raw values from the database.

Comment: @Cristiano I tried to follow you steps to achieve this but I still get the http error. I've created an app (called fcsp-db), copied the token and the secret and inside that folder is my uploads folder. When I try to upload a file with Media->Add new it is uploaded to my local uploads folder and not to the dropbox. I'm certainly doing something wrong here. But what?

Comment: Did you add my code to functions.php? Are you including/requiring or autoloading [thephpleague/flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) and their [Dropbox Adapter](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-dropbox)? Are you using Apache or Nginx? Do you know where is the error log for Apache/Nginx and PHP?

Comment: I did add your code to my functions.php. About thephpleage/filesystem and their DropBox adapter... no, i did not. Should I have? And if so... how? It is on my development site on my local machine with MAMP-> Apache. Sorry I do not know where the error log is (if any excist.). Sorry for my ignorance....

Comment: When the function is in place and I go to Dashoboard -> Media no thumbnails are shown. From this I'm concluding that my WP is reaching out for the DropBox folder but can't reach it. Tried to create a new app with a different folder name (and yes, I update the credentials in the function) to no avail. Any idea?

Comment: I edited the answer to include instructions on how to install the dependencies needed for this to work. Do you know how to use the command line? Are you on Windows, OSX or Linux?

Comment: I'm on OSX and I'm not very experienced with Terminal. I don't know if this is helpful but this is the first part of the error I get: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local' not found in /Users/adri/Documents/websites/htdocs/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/functions.php:309` Anyway, thank you for your help because I really want this to work. I will follow the steps given and let you know.

Comment: I tried to follow your steps and did get a bit further. It is not shouting about the Flysystem and adapters anymore but now I get this error: `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Users/adri/Documents/websites/htdocs/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.8/lib/php') in /Users/adri/Documents/websites/htdocs/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/functions.php on line 280` Did I do anything wrong (again)?

Comment: Those errors mean you didn't install the needed libraries with Composer. I guess we need to open the chat to discuss this, but I do not have the 15 points necessary to move to it

Comment: I was indeed thinking that something went wrong I got this message in the Terminal: `Adris-MBP:twentytwelve-child adri$ composer install -o
-bash: composer: command not found` Don't know why, I thought I follow the steps described. Although I have enough points I don't see an option to initate a chat from my side also. Should I try it again as sudo?

Comment: I tried it again this morning and at first I was not able to do download it with https. It worked with http though. Message: All settings correct for using composer Composer succesfuly installed to /Users/myhomedirectory/composer.phar. I see it in my home directory. Then I'm getting this error in the terminal when running `composer install -o` : `command not found`

Comment: Try `/Users/myhomedirectory/composer.phar install -o`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130080/discussion-between-a3o-and-cristiano-baptista).

Answer (score 0):

that's an interesting idea, but WordPress uses DB relations in order to manage the uploaded images - so i think you must handle the images through the media uploader. TL:DR; - you can't.